# How configure the Spring Security to allow use hasPermission in the JSP page?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying use hasPermission in my jsp pages from my spring project. I already use this with no problem in the methods from my controller / service classes. Reading the article:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#the-accesscontrollist-tag

from official documentation, I understood that for use this in my JSP pages I will need implement a class derived from DefaultPermission which would be loaded from a custom AclService class.

My problem it's i can't find any information of how implement all that classes, and even don't know if this approach it's the only one or if I understood the subject in the right way (the official documentation is very brief about this subject, and in the rest of internet i can't find more information).

Anyone can point me in the right direction here? Maybe indicate some tutorial or sample of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have done.  I created my own permission evaulator:

```
public class MyPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
...
}
```

Then I configured spring to use that evaulator via

```
<beans:bean id="expressionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
      <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="webExpressionHandler" 
    class="com.bulb.learn.webapp.security.CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="my.domain.MyPermissionEvaluator" />
```

That way all expression handlers have access to my evaulator.

Then, in JSP (actually, I am using jspx), I can make tags like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
...
<sec:authorize access="hasPermission(#childUnit, 'read')">
    ...
</sec:authorize>
```

Hope that gets you heading in the right direction.

Comment: Ok, works partially. I change the tag sec:accesscontrollist I was using to sec:authorize, but now even when the user has the permission, the element inside the tag isn't displayed. Also, the eclipse indicate an error related to this tag ('Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)'), despite the application being built and executed without errors.

Comment: until now I add the tag to this pages: https://github.com/klebermo/lojavirtual/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/jsp/privado/permissao/altera.jsp and https://github.com/klebermo/lojavirtual/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/jsp/privado/usuario/listagem.jsp

Comment: looking at your code, it looks like you need to pull in the security tags via: <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>